# How to Stop InstallShield from Changing the name of my "company Web address"?

Tags: installshield

I am using the limited version of InstallShield in Visual Studio 2012. The first entry in the "ProjectAssistant/Application Information" is to "Specify your company name."  Further down you can "Specify your company Web address."   This is good.

But, InstallShield  sometimes builds a "company Web address" as a function of the company name.  InstallShield, however, gets it wrong.  It does not build the correct web address.  This wouldn't  be a problem if InstallShield would stop overwriting  the correct web address which I have entered (times too numerous to count).

It's a crap shoot.  InstallShield has an inconsistent way of changing this on me, while I'm changing other parts of the install program.  During a session with InstallShield the correct web address may, or may not be, replaced with an incorrect web address, behind my back.

Has anyone else seen this problem?  Any fixes or work-arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add a comment rather than an answer but I don't have enough rep.  I see the same issue in InstallShield 2013 Professional Edition.  You can set the company web address in the Project Assistant, but it keeps getting overwritten.  My searches have not found any solutions, or even an acknowledgement from InstallShield that this issue exists.